# How do I connect to a local SQLite in Java without this ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to set up a simple Java application to connect to a SQLite database but keep receiving:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.jdbc.
```

I've downloaded the sqlite jdbc driver jar and placed it in the same directory as the .java, and I'm compiling on the command line with:

```
javac -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar sqlite3test.java
```

At runtime I then get the above exception. Below is the code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class sqlite3test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Connection c = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:cs261.db");
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    }
}
```

How do I fix this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you **execute** your application? You show how you compile, not how you execute. My guess is you didn't specify the sqlite dependency on the classpath when **running** the application. Note that when you compile, you probably don't need the sqlite dependency (as long as you programmed against the JDBC interfaces).

Comment: Are you suggesting running like 'java -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar sqlite3test'? Because that just gives me an error saying 'Could not find or load main class'

Comment: No, you need `java -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar;. sqlite3test` (replace the `;` with `:` if you are not on Windows)

Comment: I get a SQLException:  No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:cs261.db  from that still.

Comment: Is that `Class.forName` still in place, or did you remove it?

Comment: The issue is the same with or without it.

Comment: I downloaded `sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar`, copied your code, put both in the same folder, compiled it with `javac *.java` and then ran it with `java -cp sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar;. sqlite3test` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the database version installed, in my case it was: `SQLite version 3.8.2`

I am using `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.9.1.jar` which is the greater version number than of the database installed and it is working perfectly.

You have to make sure the jar file version should be greater than or equal to the database version installed in your system.

From the latest version of java (from Java 6+) you don't need to load your class file.

**Remove the following line and try it should work.**

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

**Note:** I suggest you to rename your class name from `sqlite3test` to `Sqlite3Test` though its not mandatory. According to the JAVA code convention class name should always start with Caps letter.

There are different ways to load the driver into your classpath:

- place the jar into the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext folder
- using maven dependencies
- using java -cp
- if you are using the IDE like eclipse then right click the project -> build path -> configure build path -> libraries -> add external jars and locate your jar there.

For your reference : http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/

Comment: If I remove that line I get this error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:cs261.db

Comment: try placing the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar file inside the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext folder and see

Comment: I still get the same SQLException :(

Comment: Which java version you are using?

java -version    on your terminal

Comment: Version 1.7.1_121

Comment: I also had the same issue and it was due to the mismatch between the database version installed and the version of jar file used. 

Please check your database version and use the .jar file greater or equal to the database version. I will update my  answer too.

Comment: I can only find the jar for SQLite JDBC v3.16 online and I have SQLite v3.17, I've downloaded and tried the latset JAR I can find and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the jar version is lower than the database version that's why it is not working. If you download the same version of database and install then it should work.

Comment: I've changed to using SQLite 3.16.2 and I'm using the JDBC jar v3.16.2 and I still have the SQLException issue

Comment: Did you removed the old jar which you have placed inside the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext folder

Comment: Yes and replaced it with the new one.

Comment: Advising people to put stuff in `lib/ext` is bad advise. It is only for extensions to the JDK, and it is deprecated and will be removed in Java 9.

Comment: agree @MarkRotteveel that's why I have mentioned all the options in my answer.

Comment: @Adam Lewis please make a note of it.

Comment: I have removed the JAR from the /jre/lib/ext

Comment: @AdamLewis have you been able to solve your problem?